How to get project data (product, version) for published release in net 6
It is hard to get project data (product, version) in case if project was build as Published Release (In VS: Build -> Publish Selection).
This way not working
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var version = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(assembly.Location);

because have no access to Assembly.
I found solution
GetType().Assembly.GetName().Version.ToString();

but this way I can get just version not other project attributes (Company, Product).
How can I get all project data? Maybe need to some configure publish?
Once again:

Assembly NOT worked (unavailable) in case of Published Release but all OK on debug or run from code
P.S. Publish settings

P.P.S. Try to run on "old" code

Push F10

Looks like it try to execute next line
var version = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(assembly.Location);


Using Reflection and then Assembly we can pull those information. If you could create a service for that then I think you could get the version name by GetName().Version.ToString() and for product name you can write assembly.GetName().Name and for compnay name you could write AssemblyCompanyAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(_assembly, typeof(AssemblyCompanyAttribute) then directly extract attribute.Company

Looks like this is working
var version = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]);

or
var version = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(Environment.ProcessPath);

Found in this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview?tabs=vs#api-incompatibility


but this way I can get just version not other project attributes
(Company, Product). How can I get all project data? Maybe need to some
configure publish?

Well, according to your description and scenario, you might heard about Reflection. Within Reflection, you would seen AssemblyName class like below:

Using AssemblyName class you could get Company,  Version and Product Name along many more information which usually available in assembly.
If you navigate to your project properties, You would seen following tab:

So, you could get all the information here using AssemblyName.
Let's have a look at the example in practice:
In order to get Company,  Version and Product Name, I will use and interface and service as a Singleton and then Inject as a service in program.cs file.
Class:
public class ProjectInfo
{
public string? ProductName { get; set; }
public string? Version { get; set; }
public string? Company { get; set; }
}
Note: You could add any property which you need from assembly.
Interface:
public interface IAssemblyInfoService
{
    string GetProductName();
    string GetVersion();
    string GetCompany();
}

Implementation:
public class AssemblyInfoService : IAssemblyInfoService
{
    private readonly Assembly _assembly;

    public AssemblyInfoService()
    {
        _assembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
    }

    public string GetProductName()
    {
        return _assembly.GetName().Name;
    }

    public string GetVersion()
    {
        return _assembly.GetName().Version.ToString();
    }

    public string GetCompany()
    {
        var attribute = (AssemblyCompanyAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(_assembly, typeof(AssemblyCompanyAttribute));
        return attribute != null ? attribute.Company : "Unknown";
    }
}

program.cs:
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAssemblyInfoService, AssemblyInfoService>();

Pull the information:
private readonly IAssemblyInfoService _assemblyInfoService;

public YourControllerOrService(IAssemblyInfoService assemblyInfoService)
{
    _assemblyInfoService = assemblyInfoService;
}

public List<string> InspectionType { get; private set; }

public void OnGet()
{
    var productName = _assemblyInfoService.GetProductName();
    var version = _assemblyInfoService.GetVersion();
    var company = _assemblyInfoService.GetCompany();
}

Output:




Note: Please refer to this official document to check what information you could extact or what do you need.

Assembly NOT worked (unavailable) in case of Published Release (I added it once again in general question)

Thanks for your response, may I know if you are getting any error or anything?

I added "P.P.S." in general question
